# Looking for Scene maker based on Social app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, web, progressive-web-apps

**I'm looking for Scene or Board maker**

Like Papayoot site to manage a state of room behind the IM environment

Currently when I'm playing with Whatsapp and need to extend it for any scene, I totally find my self blocked by app limitations.

After a deep searching over the net I found a nice app that can give me a added value content

Are you familiar with other similar apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For canvas 2D app that are not align on native app i'm really recommend on using pure graphics engine like PixiJS or doing this direcyly via Web Assembly or other Web API Interface.
In any case On-Boardy by Papayoot should extend their service to web!

Answer (score 0):

Looking into On-Boardy app by Papayoot and i think it relevant only for mobile/tablet devices.
It's pretty nice app but it's come without web interface!.

Ps 
Papayoot function as scene builder or board builder.

Comment: Anyway can you recommended about other good solution to Papayoot, for example... collaboration for GUI / UI canvas drawing and 2D apps ?